# Edit/Import is disable in MYSQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

[image]

What should I enable to get the other options in MySQL Workbench (version 6.0)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The edit elements in the toolbar only show up if your result is actually editable. There can be many reasons why this is not the case. Only resultsets form single table select queries can be edited and the result must include a unique key (in order to let MySQL Workbench address changed rows).

Comment: Thank you Mike,
But, My result set has PK and it is pulling the data from one table.

Comment: Please add your query to your question then and also a screenshot of the tab area of the result sets (to see if there's a read only label or Apply/Cancel buttons).

Answer (score 0):

try editing with the option edit table data,or try editing data directly in the output you get  as a result ,an option will come to apply or cancel that will update your data .
the option of apply/cancel is sometimes shows disabled but try moving to other tabs/columns it works for me you can try this.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  I think you have answered some thing not related to my question